# random values each loop using Velocity.js

Tags: javascript, loops, velocity.js

I'm currently creating a little game using Velocity.js for the movement. I have a sequence of movements that i want to loop 5 times but each time the loop is initiated, i'd like the distance travelled to be random.

Here's what I have currently but I'm aware the values are set before the loop is run and don't change throughout - Would really appreciate some help with getting the values to be randomly generated each loop.

```
var $horse = $('#horseGame');

$horse.on('click', '#race', function(){

    var $box = $(this).siblings('.box'),
        $distance = 10,
        $timeTaken = 500;

    $distance = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + $distance),
    $timeTaken = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2000) + $timeTaken);

    console.log($distance + " + " + $timeTaken);

    var race = [
        {
            elements: $box,
            properties: {
                left: $distance
            },
            options: {
                duration: $timeTaken,
                loop: 5
            }
        }
    ];
    $.Velocity.RunSequence(race);

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions as values on velocityjs and the return value will be used for that property, check [Value Functions](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#valueFunctions)

I'm not sure if it is what you need but it may help

```js
var $box = $('.box');

$box.velocity({
  translateX: function(i, total) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 200;
  }
}, 2000);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey - yeah i have looked at these but using the 'loop' option, it seems to just re-use the random value originally created. It doesn't re-generate it each iteration... if that makes sense.

Comment: I think that loop option is only for play the same animation n times. 
If you need to  change values on each iteration you could handle looping logic by yourself, see this example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AldoRomo88/aph45tu8/)